# Is there a word to describe someone who over responds to the judgement of others?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

Is there a word to describe someone who overreacts to the judgement of others, i.e., they over-correct their behavior or are overly fearful of the judgement of others?

Comment: Thin-skinned maybe?

Comment: @ Old Brixtonian: Thank you for your comment. This word word is true to the desired form; but I was hoping for something a little more from-a-psych-dictionary sounding. I will try doing a synonym search!

Comment: Tractable has a whiff of the dictionary. Over-sensitive?

Comment: I hesitate to give this as a definitive answer but feel that the attributes of sensitivity and reaction are to some extent combined in terms such as oversensitive, hypersensitive, overreactive.

Comment: @ Old Brixtonian: Thank you, I went with hyper-sensitive but may switch to tractable.

Comment: _Manipul[at]able_ is probably more common than _tractable_ in this sense.

Comment: Such a one might also tend to be conformist and a slave to fashion.